# Generate JSON String

Tags: java, android

I have this json String right now:

```
private static final String JSON_REQUEST = "{ \"username\" : \"myusername\" ,\"password\" : \"mypassword\" , \"name\" : \"myname\"}";
```

Instead of myusername, mypassword, myname I want to add variables like this

```
String username = user.getText.toString;
String password = password.getText.toString;
String name= name.getText.toString;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous, but what i believe is, you want the values to be parameterized in which case you can do is,create a template like this

```
private static final String JSON_REQUEST_TEMPLATE = "{ \"username\" : \"%s\" ,\"password\" : \"%s\" , \"name\" : \"%s\"}";
```

and then replace the values with the values like

```
String JSON_REQUEST = String.format(JSON_REQUEST_TEMPLATE, user.getText.toString, password.getText.toString, name.getText.toString);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to replace:**

```
"username" with -> "+username+"
```

Likewise, to it for other fields too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a String formatter

```
private static final String JSON_REQUEST_PATTERN = "{ \"username\" : \"%s\" ,\"password\" : \"%s\" , \"name\" : \"%s\"}";

String username = user.getText.toString;
String password = password.getText.toString;
String name= name.getText.toString;
String jsonRequest = String.format(JSON_REQUEST_PATTERN, username, password, name);
```

Or, in Kotlin

```
val jsonRequest = "{ \"username\" : \"$username\" ,\"password\" : \"$password\" , \"name\" : \"$name\"}"
```